# Pass a Variable to SQL Stored Procedure ByRef?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to assign a value to a variable, pass it to a stored proc, and then within the stored proc: 1.) use the value passed in, 2.) change the value assigned to the variable, and 3.) pass the variable back out?

I am attempting to setup a "Time Hack" that I can intersperse throughout procedures to check which statements are running slowly.  Below is an example of the procedure and a call to it.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_TIME_HACK_TEST]
    @TITLE VARCHAR(255),
    @START_TIME DATETIME OUT
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT @TITLE + ': ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE() - @START_TIME,13),12)
    SET @START_TIME = GETDATE()
END
GO

DECLARE @x int = 0
DECLARE @T DATETIME = GETDATE()
Print '@T Value at Beginning: ' + convert(VARCHAR(50),@T,21)
WHILE @x < 1000000
    SET @x += 1
EXEC usp_TIME_HACK_TEST
    @TITLE = 'Test Run', 
    @START_TIME = @T
Print '@T Value at End: ' + convert(VARCHAR(50),@T,21)
```

Here's what the result looks like.  It looks like @START_TIME got treated as an input variable, and the procedure did not change the value of @T.  Why did this happen if the variable was declared as an output variable?

```
@T Value at Beginning: 2016-07-27 11:21:19.720
Test Run: 00:00:00:607
@T Value at End: 2016-07-27 11:21:19.720
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `OUT[PUT]` in the calling code too.

```
EXEC dbo.usp_TIME_HACK_TEST
    @TITLE = 'Test Run', 
    @START_TIME = @T OUTPUT
```

BTW: Regarding your stated goal there are built in DMVs [that can be queried](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/long-running-queries/) to get information about long running statements already, no need to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Yup.  dumb mistake.  I'd just never tried this before and thought maybe the idea was wrong.  Thanks a lot of the quick response!

Comment: Never used DMVs before.  Looks like an entire world that would take me a while to get a grasp on.  Would `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` be the one I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, also `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` for higher level per procedure stats.